# List member reference

Tags: r, list, reference

I have  a list of strings like this, and I want to get all the brand names:

```
    s = c("FERRARI - 612 SCAGLIETTI" ,"PORSCHE - 918",  "ASTON MARTIN - DBS")
    tt= strsplit(s," -")
```

but here `tt` is a list of lists. How could slice this `tt`? I tried

```
    tt[[1:length(tt)]][1]
```

but got this error:

```
    Error in tt[[1:length(tt)]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by a `-` followed by other characters and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s*-.*", "", s)
#[1] "FERRARI"      "PORSCHE"      "ASTON MARTIN"
```

---

Regarding the 'tt', it is a `list`, so we can loop through the `list` with `lapply/sapply/vapply` etc and get the first element

```
sapply(tt, head, 1)
#[1] "FERRARI"      "PORSCHE"      "ASTON MARTIN"
```

Comment: This is smart. Thank you.